# How to make inputs more DRY in React Apollo?

Tags: apollo-client, react-apollo

How can I reuse variable arguments in GQL Apollo React? e.g. in a situation where the inputs are the same but we need different data corresponding for a different situation.

Is there a way to define this inside or outside of this query call?

```
const REQUEST_1 = gql`
  query QueryA(
    $page: Int
    $a: String
    $b: Number
    $etc: EtcFilter
  ) {
    getData(
      limit: 24
      page: $page
      a: $a
      b: $b
      etc: $etc
    ) {
      total
      result {
        id
        time
        location
      }
    }
  }
  `
const REQUEST_2 = gql`
  query QueryA(
    $page: Int
    $a: String
    $b: Number
    $etc: EtcFilter
  ) {
    getData(
      limit: 24
      page: $page
      a: $a
      b: $b
      etc: $etc
    ) {
      total
      result {
        postContent
        date
        coordinates
        id
      }
    }
  }
  `
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your Query example, the short/sad answer is **you cannot do that**.

According to the [current GraphQL specs](https://spec.graphql.org/October2021/#sec-Language.Variables):

> Variables must be defined at the top of an operation and are in scope throughout the execution of **that** operation.

*That operation* is referring to a query/mutation, in your example, `REQUEST_1` and `REQUEST_2` are two separate operations.

---

There is an open issue in the [graphql-specs](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-spec/issues/204) that could possible address this use case, but it is not anywhere near implementation.

---

#### Edit with one operation example (from comments)

You could combine both operations in one, in something like this:

```js
const REQUEST = gql`
  query QueryA(
    $page: Int
    $a: String
    $b: Number
    $etc: EtcFilter
  ) {
    getData(
      limit: 24
      page: $page
      a: $a
      b: $b
      etc: $etc
    ) {
      total
      result1: result {
        id
        time
        location
      }
      result2: result {
        postContent
        date
        coordinates
        id
      }
    }
  }
  `
```

because you would be querying the same `result` object just with different fields, you will have to give [an alias](https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#aliases) to it.

This will of course make the full query every time, but it will keep it cleaner of input parameters.

Comment: Okay I see thanks. What if I combined them into one operation? Would it still be possible to execute the queries separately or would that force them to happen at the same time?

Comment: Yes, if you would combine it in one operation it would always execute both requests every time.

Comment: @darkace, I've updated the answer with an example based on your comment. How you could combine in one operation.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use Fragments:

```
const result1 = gql`
    fragment ResultFields on PaginationResult {
      id
      time
      location
    }
`;

const result2 = gql`
    fragment ResultFields on PaginationResult {
      postContent
      date
      coordinates
      id
    }
`;

const query = `query QueryA(
    $page: Int
    $a: String
    $b: Number
    $etc: EtcFilter
  ) {
    getData(
      limit: 24
      page: $page
      a: $a
      b: $b
      etc: $etc
    ) {
      total
      result {
        ...ResultFields
      }
    }
  }`

const REQUEST_1 = gql`${query}${result1}`
const REQUEST_2 = gql`${query}${result2}`
```

I made up the type `PaginationResult`, it depends on the type of result.

Not 100% sure if the above will apply to your situation but you can find more info here: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/fragments/